# CSS site layout with inline-block

Tags: css

I tried to create a new layout for my site using inline-block instead of float.

```
<div id="container">

<div class="row"><!-- HEADER -->

    <div class="pan1">
        <div class="content">
             HEADER LEFT PANEL <br /><br />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="pan2">
        <div class="content">
             HEADER RIGHT PANEL <br/></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div><!-- END HEADER -->

<div class="row"><!-- MAIN -->

    <div class="pan3">
        <div class="content">
             MAIN LEFT PANEL <br /><br />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="pan4">
        <div class="content">
             MAIN RIGHT PANEL <br/></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div><!-- END MAIN -->

</div>
```

CSS

```
body { 
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
font-size: 12px; 
background-color: #f5f6f7; 
} 

#container { 
width: 960px; 
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
background: #ccc;
} 

.row { 
margin-top: 10px; 
background: #fff; 
padding: 0px;
} 

.pan1  { 
width: 700px; 
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
*zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
padding: 0px;
font-size: 0;
} 

.pan2  { 
width: 256px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
*zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
padding: 0px;
font-size: 0;
} 

.pan3  { 
width: 500px; 
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
*zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
padding: 0px;
font-size: 0;
} 

.pan4  { 
width: 456px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
*zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
padding: 0px;
font-size: 0;
}

.content {
padding: 0px;
border: 1px solid #000;
font-size: 12px;
}
```

unfortunately I can not understand why it is not considered the hack to remove the white space between panels inline-block **and also the main block turns out to be not aligned with my header block**. Can you give me any suggestions on how I could make a correct layout? thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the alignment thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is within your html tags. you put other/extra ending `</div>` that is why the main block is not aligned like the header block

to remove the white space you will need to do this

```
<div>
 // content
</div><div>
// content
</div>

<div id="container">
    <div class="row"><!-- HEADER -->
        <div class="pan1">
            <div class="content">
                 HEADER LEFT PANEL <br /><br />
            </div>
        </div><div class="pan2">
            <div class="content">
                 HEADER RIGHT PANEL <br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- END HEADER -->
    <div class="row"><!-- MAIN -->
        <div class="pan3">
            <div class="content">
                 MAIN LEFT PANEL <br /><br />
            </div>
        </div><div class="pan4">
            <div class="content">
                 MAIN RIGHT PANEL <br/>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div><!-- END MAIN -->
</div><!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

look at this for the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3HNEs/)

Comment: thanks for your solution, but I've read that setting font-size: 0 in the parent you should get the same result. (</ div> <div>), although in my case it really does not work. Can you tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

To remove spaces between blocks, you can try to write your html like this:

```
<div>
...
</div><div>
...
</div>
```

Having element start just after an other one will prevent the browser to add whitespaces between elements. It also means that you can't have newlines between elements. If I was you, I could instead think of using a minificator that will remove unnecessary whitespaces.